How to Hide Panels in Google Colab?
bottom two panels are not wanted
New to using colab; somehow these bottom panels that contain nothing showed up, and I'm not sure how to get rid of them. I assume it's some keyboard shortcut of some kind? Thanks in advance for your help.
I tried hitting the 3 dots, and I'm able to adjust to a vertical layout; this has the same issue, just that the blank panels are on the right instead.
